# show contents of html in webview page wise android

Tags: android

I am working on epub reader. I am successfully getting the html content of book along with table of contents and cover page. Currently the content is displayed in scrolling webview but I want to show the contents of book page wise.

Comment: You can do it two way: 1: Change the CSS according to your requirement 2: Handle the HTML content programmatically to show it as per your requirement.

Comment: Are you loading any epub file form network?

Comment: No, i am just loading epub from sd card